# What does "that" mean in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, that

> This is perhaps a true definition of self-confidence: the ability to look at the world without the need to look for instances that pleases your ego.

Hello, 
I came across this sentence and wondered what "that" indicated in the text above. 
At first I thought the relative pronoun "that" indicated "instances." But due to the verb "please**s**," i think "that" might indicate "the need," because of the verb "pleases."

If so, the sentence above means: without the need which(=the need) pleases  your ego.

But for me, it doesn't make sense.

Could anyone help me? 
The original sentence in a part of the article below.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/science-choice/201504/what-is-confirmation-bias

Comment: It is not a relative pronoun but a meaningless clause subordinator whose function is simply to introduce the relative clause "that please your ego".

Comment: This would be better asked at English Language Learners

Comment: "Pleases" seems to me to be an error in this sentence. I agree that the sentence doesn't make sense unless it is replaced with "please."

Answer (score 1):

From the grammatical point of view, it seems that the [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/science-choice/201504/what-is-confirmation-bias) is not a well-written one. The following sentences are from the same article and I do not think they are all grammatical except may be the last two sentences which can be interpreted as example of the *ellipsis*. So, the OP's sentence should have been: *"...instances that please your ego."*

> - "Self-deception can be like a drug, numbing you from harsh reality,    or ***turning a blind eye to*** the tough matter for gathering evidence and 
>     thinking."
> - "There is a limited evidence that ***believing that you will recover***    **help** reduce the level of stress hormones..."
> - "Disconfirmation would require look for evidence to disprove it."
> - "The take home lesson here is that set your hypothesis and look for    instances to prove that you are wrong."

Comment: Though true, this doesn't answer the OP's question in any way.

Comment: What do you think the OP's question is and what do you understand from my words: **So, the OP's sentence should have been: "...instances that please your ego."**?

Comment: I think the OP's question is "*What does “that” mean in this sentence?*". I understand from your sentence that *please* shouldn't have a third person S. This doesn't answer the OP's question, it seems to me.

Comment: Yes, the OP has this idea and his own explanations show that. Citing other example sentences of carelessness from the same article where the OP's sentence comes from, I have pointed out that it's a grammatical error which may have occurred accidentally.

Comment: Whether it's *please* or *pleases* doesn't make any difference to the answer to the OP's question though.